# iOS's ipa distribution for testing

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I have made an app for iPad and I would like to send this for testing to a friend. If I send the .ipa by email can he install this .ipa on his iPad? If he can't, what's the better way to install my .ipa on his iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/).

Answer (score 14):

1. you need the UDID of this iPad.
2. add it to the [test devices](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/) of your ios developer account.
3. add the device to a adhoc distribution [provisioning profile](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action)
4. and build your app with it.
5. then you send the ipa to him
6. he can install the app into itunes and sync his ipad with itunes

   - alternatively install it with iphone configuration utility (windows or mac)
   - or in Xcode using Windows > Devices > Select your device > Installed Apps

Answer (score 3):

You need to know UDID of the iPad. [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) requires you to compile the app with the UDID added to the provisioning profile.

If you don't know the UDID you might use some services like [www.aironapp.com](http://www.aironapp.com) which gets the UDID of the device automatically and resigns the application with the new UDID.