# Flutter Build ipa file to distribute for testing

Tags: flutter, ipa

I am working on a flutter project on a MAC system. As I do not own an iPhone, I want to build a test ipa file to send to another user. Is it possible to do so without a paid Developer Account.
How can it be done.

When searching online I am unable to get a definite answer regarding the process needed to build a ipa file for testing. Hope  someone can help me.

Flutter 3.0.5 , Mac Mini M1 with Monterey 12.4
hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not use `ipa` or send `ipa` to anyone without `Enroll Apple Developer account`. Yes you can use your physical device via cable Without developer account but for ipa you have to Enroll first.

Answer (score 1):

As general iOS developer, you can only run app on Apple device through usb cable on debug mode. The only way to build ipa file is use paid Developer Account.

Comment: I've found this old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710815/ioss-ipa-distribution-for-testing. Does this approach work?

Comment: if you have iOS developer account you can publish your app on Apple TestFlight app and then your tester could access it there. @Andrey